# Issues launching SpiderOakONE on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using Cron

Tags: server, scripts, cron, systemd, syslog

I have an instance of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running on a server. I need SpiderOakONE to launch automatically on reboot without the user having to log in. I decided this would be best suited to cron. I created a crontab for my current user using `crontab -e` and added this line:

```
@reboot sleep 5 && /sbin/start-stop-daemon -b -x /usr/bin/SpiderOakONE -S
```

The systemd cron service is active and my syslog says that cron starts the job but nothing else. There are no error logs or info logs related to SpiderOakONE.

To test, I rebooted my server and waited a few minutes before testing whether the server will sync with SpiderOakONE and it did not work.

Is the cron job set correctly? Am I perhaps not waiting long enough for SpiderOak to start? It takes a good long time to sync when a user logs into the server so perhaps thats happening but I'm really not sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `@reboot` means the start of the cron-daemon. Could it be, that this is started, before the network is up?

Comment: The `start-stop-daemon` command needs `--start` as first option. Besides this, I think this is not the right command in this setting. Maybe remove the `start-stop-daemon` command might work even better.

Comment: `--start` is equivalent with `-S` no? I'll change it round. Also, how would I launch the executable without the `start-stop-daemon`? What would I use instead of the daemon? Would cron just recognise that `/usr/bin/SpiderOakONE` is an executable and start that?

Comment: `@reboot sleep 5 && /usr/bin/SpiderOakONE` might work.

Comment: Thanks, will try - are you suggesting that cron will recognise that path as an executable?

Comment: @Marco I did that and it did the same thing in syslog. The kernel log then logged a lot of starting stuff that I dont remember it doing before. It seemed to activate network manager etc etc after the crontab. Should I increase the `sleep`? Or is there another cron hook I could use.

Comment: If you have root access to the server you can use systemd with dependencies. Otherwise the easiest way is to increase the sleep. More sophisticated would be to check the network, e.g. with `systemd-networkd-wait-online`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, SpiderOakONE has a built in `--headless` option you can add on launch.

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /usr/bin/SpiderOakONE --headless 2>&1 | logger -t SpiderOakLog
```

This was my final crontab. The `2>&1 ...` part isn't necessary, it just allows the info/errors to be logged to `syslog` instead of an MTA error.